# SQL Express: Primary filegroup is full -> What workarounds are there?

Tags: sql, ssms, filegroup

as it seems I manoeuvred myself into a dead end in SQL but definitely need to solve my tasks with the resources that I have at hand...

I use SQL Server Express and I need to process a rather (not very) large table.
Due to the fact that SQL Express is limited to a max size of 10GB per filegroup I am not able to run my beautiful scripts.

I already shrinked the database as well as the file but this wasn't enough.

Now I am thinking about splitting the data into two (or more) filegroups but I don't know how to do that and if it is even possible... .

Is there anyone here that knows a workaround?

PS: I can't split the original data due to the nature of the tasks/manipulations

Comment: You need some other version of SQL server then - or even some other (free) DBMS. All such hacks (splitting data over multiple files etc) are temporary - data volume tends to always increase.

Comment: Hi Avro, thanks a lot for your instant answer. Do you by any chance know another free DBMS that I try that can store larger files than SQL Server Express?

Comment: PostgreSQL comes to mind, although I have not used any others than MS SQL server. You should wait for some real answers - my comment here may not reflect reality very well.

Comment: There are [many RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems), each with its own limitations. [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) looks like the place for your question (part of the StackExchange network, you can use the same account) if you need an alternative.

Comment: Are you using the DB for commercial use or for your own private use? Most of the main DB vendors (Oracle, MS, etc) have free versions of their main products that you can use as long as you work within their licence conditions (i.e. not for commercial/production DBs)